# ActiveRecord Callbacks List

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I've been going through the rails source for a while now, and I don't think there's a better way of getting the list of *all* callbacks other than: `ActiveRecord::Callbacks::CALLBACKS` – which is a constant list.

Meaning if you're using a gem like devise_invitable that adds a new callback called `:invitation_accepted` with the score `:after` and `:before` then `ActiveRecord::Callbacks::CALLBACKS` will not work.

Do you know of an easy fix, other than opening up rails modules and making sure there's an internal list of call-backs per model class?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can call `Model._save_callbacks` to get a list of all callbacks on save. 
You can then filter it down to what kind you need e.g. `:before` or `:after` like this:

```
Model._save_callbacks.select {|cb| cb.kind == :before}
```

Works the same for `Model._destroy_callbacks` etc.

Comment: Also check the docs for more detailed info: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks

Answer (score 20):

The [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) say "There are nineteen callbacks in total"... but they don't seem to say what all of those 19 actually are!

For those who Googled "list of all ActiveRecord callbacks" like I did, here's the list (found by using `ActiveRecord::Callbacks::CALLBACKS` as described in the question):

```
:after_initialize
:after_find
:after_touch
:before_validation
:after_validation
:before_save
:around_save
:after_save
:before_create
:around_create
:after_create
:before_update
:around_update
:after_update
:before_destroy
:around_destroy
:after_destroy
:after_commit
:after_rollback
```

Comment: Oh, and I've just discovered they're listed [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html), in the guides. Still, I hope this answer saves someone some Google time in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you simply want to trigger callbacks, you can use the `#run_callbacks(kind)` method:

```
o = Order.find 123 # Created with SQL
o.run_callbacks(:create)
o.run_callbacks(:save)
o.run_callbacks(:commit)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're working in a Rails version prior to the `._save_callbacks` method, you can use the following:

```
# list of callback_chain methods that return a CallbackChain
Model.methods.select { |m| m.to_s.include? "callback" }.sort

# get all methods in specific call back chain, like after_save
Model.after_save_callback_chain.collect(&:method)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to propose most universal solution.

It works even when gems are declaring custom callbacks e.g. [paranoia](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia) and `after_real_destroy`

To list all callbacks

```
Model.methods.select { |m| m.to_s.include? "callback" }.sort
```

Then you can get given callbacks if you type method name e.g.

```
Model._update_callbacks
Model._real_destroy_callbacks
Model._destroy_callbacks
```

If you list all callbacks, then you can find callback you need by checking `@filter` instance variable e.g.

```
require 'pp'
Activity._destroy_callbacks.each_with_index { |clbk,index| puts "#{index}-------\n#{clbk.pretty_inspect}" } ; nil 

# [...]

#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x00007ff14ee7a968
 @chain_config=
  {:scope=>[:kind, :name],
   :terminator=>
    #<Proc:0x00007ff13fb825f8@/Users/mypc/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.1.16/lib/active_model/callbacks.rb:103 (lambda)>,
   :skip_after_callbacks_if_terminated=>true},
 @filter=
  #<Proc:0x00007ff14ee7ac10@/Users/mypc/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.16/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:135 (lambda)>,
 @if=[],
 @key=70337193825800,
 @kind=:before,
 @name=:destroy,
 @unless=[]>
4-------
#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x00007ff14ee3a228
 @chain_config=
  {:scope=>[:kind, :name],
   :terminator=>
    #<Proc:0x00007ff13fb825f8@/Users/mypc/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.1.16/lib/active_model/callbacks.rb:103 (lambda)>,
   :skip_after_callbacks_if_terminated=>true},
 @filter=:audit_destroy,
 @if=[],
 @key=:audit_destroy,
 @kind=:before,
 @name=:destroy,
 @unless=[]>
5-------
```

Answer (score 0):

For `after_commit` callbacks, call `Model._commit_callbacks`.

Be mindful, however, that there's a known bug in Rails (still present in Rails 5.2.2) that `after_commit` callbacks are not run in the order they are declared in the model, even tough they appear in the correct order in that `_commit_callbacks` call.

More info: [Execution order of multiple after_commit callbacks (Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625790/execution-order-of-multiple-after-commit-callbacks-rails) and  https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20911