# Execution order of multiple after_commit callbacks (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I recently found that multiple `after_commit`s defined in the same model get called in reverse order. For example

```
after_commit method1, :on => :create
after_commit method2, :on => :create
```

`method2` gets called before `method1`.

Is it always called in FILO order?

Comment: why don't you write `after_commit method1, method2, :on => :create`

so they will be executed in the manner you have defined

Comment: Interestingly, when I tried writing them in one line like you mentioned, `method2` still gets called before `method1`. My rails version is `3.0.20.13`.

Comment: So, is this behaviour fixed? Is there some document supporting this?

Comment: For the record there is a GH issue reporting this behavior: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20911 (but it is closed).

Comment: Still seeing this in Rails 6.0.3.3

Answer (score 6):

This behaviour is still present in Rails 5.2.2.1.

My solution:

```
after_commit :after_commit_callbacks, :on => :create

def after_commit_callbacks
  method1
  method2
end
```