# How do I get the Callbacks for an ActiveRecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way to be able to see what callbacks an ActiveRecord object has?
Say if I have:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :my_after_save_function
end
```

How would you see the what the after_save callback points to?

> e.g. MyModel.callbacks

I want to be able to test that my models have after_save callbacks that point to a particular function or callback class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord Callbacks List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529867/activerecord-callbacks-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found it.

You can use:

```
MyModel._save_callbacks.map(&:filter)
```

This [article](https://seaneshbaugh.com/posts/finding-all-activerecord-callbacks) helped me.